# FromCurrentSynchronizationContext, am I missing something?

Tags: c#, user-interface, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I current working an application that reads from a large binary file, which holds several thousands files, every file is being processed by some other class in application. This class returns either an object or null. I want to show a progress on the main form but for some reason I can't get my head around it.

```
int TotalFound = 0;
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext;
BufferBlock<file> buffer = new BufferBlock<file>();
DataflowBlockOptions options = new DataflowBlockOptions(){ TaskScheduler = uiScheduler, }; 
var producer = new ActionBlock<someObject>(largeFile=>{ 
    var file = GetFileFromLargeFile(largeFile);
    if(file !=null){
       TotalFound++;
       buffer.post(file);
       lblProgress.Text = String.Format("{0}", TotalFound);
    }
}, options);
```

The above code freezes my Form, even do I use "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext", why? Because when I use the code below my form updates fine

```
DataflowBlockOptions options = new DataflowBlockOptions(){ TaskScheduler = uiScheduler, }; 
var producer = new ActionBlock<someObject>(largeFile=>{ 
    var file = GetFileFromLargeFile(largeFile);
    if(file !=null){
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
          TotalFound++;
          buffer.Post(file);
       }).ContinueWith(uiTask => {
          lblProgress.Text = String.Format("{0}", TotalFound);
       },CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, uiScheduler);           
    }
});
```

I am new to this whole TPL Dataflow, so I am hoping someone could share some light on why in the second code snippet it works and in the first snippet it doesn't.

Kind regards,
Martijn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your UI is blocked is *becase* you're using `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. It causes the code to run on the UI thread, which means it will freeze if you're doing some long running action (most likely `GetFileFromLargeFile()`).

On the other hand, you have to run the `lblProgress.Text` on the UI thread.

I'm not sure you should set `lblProgress.Text` directly in this code, it look like too tight coupling to me. But if you want to do that, I think you should run just that line on the UI thread:

```
var producer = new ActionBlock<someObject>(async largeFile =>
{
    var file = GetFileFromLargeFile(largeFile);
    if (file != null)
    {
        TotalFound++;
        await buffer.SendAsync(file);
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => lblProgress.Text = String.Format("{0}", TotalFound),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
    }
});
```

But even better solution would be if you made `GetFileFromLargeFile()` asynchronous and made sure it doesn't do any long-running actions on the UI thread ([`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can help you with that). If you did that, the code of the `ActionBlock` could run on the UI thread without freezing your UI:

```
var producer = new ActionBlock<someObject>(async largeFile =>
{
    var file = await GetFileFromLargeFile(largeFile);
    if (file != null)
    {
        TotalFound++;
        await buffer.SendAsync(file);
        lblProgress.Text = String.Format("{0}", TotalFound)
    }
}, options);
```

Comment: Tnx for the explanation, makes clear to me know. Still got one question, is it better to run tasks out-side the UI thread like in your first example our does this not matter for the performance of the application?

Comment: If the task runs only for a very short time, then it doesn't matter. Otherwise, you should never run long-running tasks on the UI thread. Not because of performance, but because it will freeze your application.

Comment: Is there any other (better) way to deal with gui updates? I applied the recommended code by svick, but still my ui freezes.. In my applications there are a total of 8 ActionBlock<T> each performing a tasks on a custom object, 3 ActionBlocks perform have a MaxParallizism set to processor count which in my case is 7. All 8 ActionBlocks communicate with the gui... So in theory it could be >30 tasks wanting to update the gui. Anyone any idea?